# Algorithm to find optimal groups in 2D array

Tags: algorithm

I have a deck of 24 cards - 8 red, 8 blue and 8 yellow cards.

```
red    |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
yellow |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
blue   |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
```

I can take 3 of cards (same numbers, straight, straigh flush), whereas each of the type is scored differently.
My question is, how to calculate maximal possible score (find optimal groups) for a game in progress, where some cards are already missing.
for example:

```
red    |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
yellow |1|2|3| |5| |7|8|
blue   |1|2| |4|5|6| |8|
```

---

The score for a three-of-a-kind is:

```
1-1-1    20  
2-2-2    30  
3-3-3    40  
4-4-4    50  
5-5-5    60  
6-6-6    70  
7-7-7    80  
8-8-8    90
```

The score for a straight is:

```
1-2-3    10  
2-3-4    20  
3-4-5    30  
4-5-6    40  
5-6-7    50  
6-7-8    60
```

The score for a straight flush is:

```
1-2-3    50  
2-3-4    60  
3-4-5    70  
4-5-6    80  
5-6-7    90  
6-7-8   100
```

Comment: How is score calculated in the game?

Comment: You can see the points on [link](http://wiki.metin2.co.uk/index.php/Okey_Card_Game#Combination_and_points) there is also whole game described.

Comment: Should I add the JavaScript code to demonstrate the algorithm?

Comment: That would be great :)

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: Yep sorry for delayed feedback. It was really good idea to use bitwise operations, it is now quite fast and usable. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution which recursively tries every combination would go like this:

Start looking at combinations that have a red 8 as the highest card: three-of-a-kind r8-y8-b8, straight flush r6-r7-r8, and every possible straight *6-*7-r8. For each of these, remove the cards from the set, and recurse to check combinations with the yellow 8, then blue 8, then red 7, yellow 7, blue 7, red 6 ... until you've checked everything except the 2's and 1's; then add three-of-a-kind 2-2-2 and 1-1-1 if available. At each step, check which recursion returns the maximum score, and return this maximum.

---

Let's look at what happens in each of these steps. Say we're looking at combinations with red 8; we have available cards like:

```
red    ...|6|7|8|
yellow ...|6| |8|
blue   ...| |7|8|
```

First, use three-of-a-kind r8-y8-b8, if possible. Create a copy of the available cards, remove the 8's, and recurse straight to the 7's:

```
score = 90 + max_score(cards_copy, next = red 7)
```

(Trying the three-of-a-kind should only be done when the current card is red, to avoid duplicate solutions.)

Then, use straight flush r6-r7-r8, if possible. Create a copy of the available cards, remove r6, r7 and r8, and recurse to yellow 8:

```
score = 100 + max_score(cards_copy, next = yellow 8)
```

Then, use every possible non-flush straight containing red 8; in the example, those are r6-b7-r8, y6-r7-r8 and y6-b7-r8 (there could be up to nine). For each of these, create a copy of the available cards, remove the three cards and recurse to yellow 8:

```
score = 60 + max_score(cards_copy, next = yellow 8)
```

Then, finally, recurse without using red 8: create a copy of the available cards, remove red 8 and recurse to yellow 8:

```
score = max_score(cards_copy, next = yellow 8)
```

You then calculate which of these options has the greatest score (with the score returned by its recursion added), and return that maximum score.

---

A quick test in JavaScript shows that for a full set of 24 cards, the algorithm goes through 30 million recursions to find the maximum score 560, and becomes quite slow. However, as soon as 3 higher-value cards have been removed, the number of recursions falls below one million and it takes around 1 second, and with 6 higher-value cards removed, it falls below 20,000 and returns almost instantly.

For almost-complete sets, you could pre-compute the maximum scores, and only calculate the score once a certain number of cards have been removed. A lot of sets will be duplicates anyway; removing r6-r7-r8 will result in the same maximum score as removing y6-y7-y8; removing r6-y7-b8 is a duplicate of removing b6-y7-r8...  So first you change the input to a canonical version, and then you look up the pre-computed score. E.g. using pre-computed scores for all sets with 3 or 6 cards removed would require storing 45,340 scores.

---

As a code example, here's the JavaScript code I tested the algorithm with:

```js
function clone(array) {                                   // copy 2-dimensional array
    var copy = [];
    array.forEach(function(item) {copy.push(item.slice())});
    return copy;
}
function max_score(cards, suit, rank) {
    suit = suit || 0; rank = rank || 7;                             // start at red 8
    var max = 0;
    if (rank < 2) {                               // try 3-of-a-kind for rank 1 and 2
        if (cards[0][0] && cards[1][0] && cards[2][0]) max += 20;
        if (cards[0][1] && cards[1][1] && cards[2][1]) max += 30;
        return max;
    }
    var next_rank = suit == 2 ? rank - 1: rank;
    var next_suit = (suit + 1) % 3;
    max = max_score(clone(cards), next_suit, next_rank);    // try skipping this card
    if (! cards[suit][rank]) return max;
    if (suit == 0 && cards[1][rank] && cards[2][rank]) {           // try 3-of-a-kind
        var score = rank * 10 + 20 + max_score(clone(cards), 0, rank - 1);
        if (score > max) max = score;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {                       // try all possible straights
        if (! cards[i][rank - 2]) continue;
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (! cards[j][rank - 1]) continue;
            var copy = clone(cards);
            copy[j][rank - 1] = 0; copy[i][rank - 2] = 0;
            var score = rank * 10 - 10 + max_score(copy, next_suit, next_rank);
            if (i == suit && j == suit) score += 40;    // straight is straight flush
            if (score > max) max = score;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
document.write(max_score([[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]]));
```

An obvious way to speed up the algorithm is to use a 24-bit pattern instead of a 3x8 bit array to represent the cards; that way the array cloning is no longer necessary, and most of the code is turned into bit manipulation. In JavaScript, it's about 8 times faster:

```js
function max_score(cards, suit, rank) {
    suit = suit || 0; rank = rank || 7;                             // start at red 8
    var max = 0;
    if (rank < 2) {                               // try 3-of-a-kind for rank 1 and 2
        if ((cards &  65793) ==  65793) max += 20;     // 65793 = rank 1 of all suits
        if ((cards & 131586) == 131586) max += 30;    // 131586 = rank 2 of all suits
        return max;
    }
    var next_rank = suit == 2 ? rank - 1: rank;
    var next_suit = (suit + 1) % 3;
    var this_card = 1 << rank << suit * 8;
    max = max_score(cards, next_suit, next_rank);           // try skipping this card
    if (! (cards & this_card)) return max;
    if (suit == 0 && cards & this_card << 8 && cards & this_card << 16) { // try 3oaK
        var score = rank * 10 + 20 + max_score(cards, 0, rank - 1);
        if (score > max) max = score;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {                       // try all possible straights
        var mid_card = 1 << rank - 1 << i * 8;
        if (! (cards & mid_card)) continue;
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            var low_card = 1 << rank - 2 << j * 8;
            if (! (cards & low_card)) continue;
            var cards_copy = cards - mid_card - low_card;
            var score = rank * 10 - 10 + max_score(cards_copy, next_suit, next_rank);
            if (i == suit && j == suit) score += 40;    // straight is straight flush
            if (score > max) max = score;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
document.write(max_score(parseInt("111101110111111111011111", 2)));
//                                 B       Y       R
//                                 876543218765432187654321
```

The speed for almost-complete sets can be further improved by using the observation that if a straight flush for all three suits can be be made for the current rank, then this is always the best option. This reduces the number of recursions drastically, because nine cards can be skipped at once. This check should be added immediately after trying 3-of-a-kind for rank 1 and 2:

```js
    if (suit == 0) {                              // try straight flush for all suits
        var flush3 = 460551 << rank - 2;     // 460551 = rank 1, 2 and 3 of all suits
        if ((cards & flush3) == flush3) {
            max = rank * 30 + 90;
            if (rank > 2) max += max_score(cards - flush3, 0, rank - 3);
            return max;
        }
    }
```